# Certain file(s) in Finder cannot be opened, renamed, tagged — although all permissions, flags, etc are ok

Tags: finder, permission, filesystem, macos

### A bunch of files behave odd in Finder.

- I cannot not tag, rename, or open them.
- Opening their info dialog shows everything greyed out, no interactions possible.

### How did I get into the problem

- I did some heavy multi-stage processing of hundreds of PNG files.
- In between I duplicated a whole folder (and the files in it) to then process the files through the next stage. And tagged the files with the processing they received.
- As such I kept all intermediary stages in folders. And each file grew by a tag per each processing stage to document what was done on it specifically (they got different treatment).
- Should I mess up along the way, I could always go back phase by phase due to my incremental folder backups.
- Thank to APFS being a copy-on-write system that folder duplication worked ultra fast.
- But along the duplications and tagging something must have went wrong. In the final folder some of the files showed the odd behavior described above.

### Investigation

- Checked unix file permissions, owner, etc.
- Compared every attribute by `mdls` between one of the broken files vs. one of the working files.
- Also compared if some of the exotic Mac filesystem flags may have been set differently with `GetFileInfo -a` plus the respective attribute letter, such as `locked` or `inited`. No luck either. Found no anomalies whatsoever.
- Relaunching Finder or restarting the Mac didn't help either.

### What can be the reason for this odd behavior?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image: File in Finder cannot be renamed tagged opened due to bad creation date]

## Reason: The Creation Date of those files was broken/invalid

### After much investigation I had finally found the reason

- All the files that showed these strange symptoms had two things in common:
- **A common Finder tag which I assigned them in a massive batch assignment** (500 files or more at once).
- **They all had a Creation Date of 1984-02-24** (aka January 24th, 1984) the birth date of the Macintosh.

  - This is the fallback date if the creation date is 0 or NULL or otherwise invalid I assume.
  - So during the batch assignment of tags something broke and left the file dates in a bad state.

### How to fix these broken files

- If the creation dates don't matter to you, just set them to the same as the modification date.

  - By your tool of choice, e.g.:

    - A Better Finder Attributes
    - `SetFile -d "$(GetFileInfo -m "broken-file.ext")" broken-file.ext`
  - Or by a gratis and builtin function of Finder:

    - You can simply zip the file(s)s with Finder's integrated ZIP command.
    - Right-click file(s) > Compress.
    - All macOS metadata is preserved (Finder Tags, Spotlight Comment, dates, permissions, etc).
    - And when unzipping the file plus all metadata is restored and the broken/invalid creation dates are fixed automatically.
- In my case preserving the creation dates mattered to understand the image file genesis.

  - But due to having worked with incremental backups, I could restore them from one of the intermediary folder. And just tag them again.
  - And this time I left the Finder window in front, until all tags updated (can take some 20-60 seconds when tagging hundreds/thousands of files) not to mess it up again. I guess having done something else in Finder while the tagging process was in process caused the mess up in the first place.